# Pushing folder into github

Tags: github, commit

I was trying to push the folder on my computer to GitHub. So I created a GitHub repository, and use `git` bash command line. I didn't push the folder successfully on my first try. Then, I deleted the old GitHub repository and created a new one, and tried using the `git` bash command line to push code again. However, it shows nothing to commit.

[Here is an image to better help understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj73r.png)

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. See the meta post [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: Hint: read the error messages carefully, especially (use "git add" to track). Read on what the command does with `git help add`

Answer (score 2):

According to the image, I understand that you have made a commit but your commit was empty and you did not track any file with `git` beforehand. You typically want to track the files you want to commit. So in this case you could use `git add` before committing:

```sh
git add .
```

This should track all files in the current folder after which you could commit and push them:

```sh
git commit -m "Some message"
git push
```

Comment: Yes, I don't see a stage of the files with `git add .` or `git add <folder1>`. Since the request is to push a specific folder, I would specific that folder since it might commit sensitive files that are in the repo parent path.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new repository on git, it shows you how to properly upload data

```
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/youracc/your.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: If you check the added screenshot you will see this is exactly what OP did. Problem is that he did not add the untracked files, thus nothing was pushed.